# How to map database XML output to JAXB derived object model

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am requesting links to sources/material that will help me with the following problem (a problem because I am novice to Java/JAXB and coming from a PHP background).

I am supplied with a complex XSD that is created & maintained by an organization.  I created the java object model using JAXB 2.1.  I need to map database fields to the java/jaxb derived classes.  The database fields/elements are rendered via simple XML output.  Example of the XML database record output is as follows:

```
<PROBLEM>
<PID>262</ID>
<PROBLEM_DATE>14-DEC-10</PROBLEM_DATE>
<PROBLEM_TYPE>T</PROBLEM_TYPE>
<PROBLEM_CODE>244.9</PROBLEM_CODE>
</PROBLEM>
```

Example of of the JAXB derived class:

```
protected IvlTs problemDate;

public IvlTs getProblemDate() {
            return problemDate;
        }

public void setProblemDate(IvlTs value) {
            this.problemDate = value;
        }
```

How would I map the xml element `<PROBLEM_DATE>` to problemDate? Please advise of an article/tutorial that can help me get started. Also, the XML database extract is large, having nearly 500 fields/xml elements, is there a way to automate the mapping or must this all be done by hand?

Comment: You know you can use the XSD to generate Java classes, right? See http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbah.html.

Comment: I was able to generate the classes using the XSD.  It is the next step I am not clear about.  Which is, I am given a database record extract in the form of XML (sample of the XML is above).  I need to unmarshall that XML document.  When java unmarshalls the XML document, how do I map the database XML element to the Java Jaxb derived class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to read up on [JAXB annotations](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_6_1-JAXB-Annotations.html#JAXB%20Annotations). For this particular problem, you want to annotate the getProblemDate() method with

```
@XmlElement(name="PROBLEM_DATE")
```

If there's a common pattern, like problemDate -> PROBLEM_DATE and in general fooBar -> FOO_BAR, then it should be pretty easy to write a regex find/replace to get what you need.